# Is there any anchor tag in Onsen UI?

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a long Onsen UI page. After scrolling to the bottom of the page, I was able to load a new content in the same page. However, the page is still displayed at the same and current position.

Note: I am using ons-list. Is there any auto scroll to top in ons-list after the list is refreshed?

I wonder how I can make it to the top position after new content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors and scrolling depend only on the browser.You can use [Angular $anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) or anything similar to handle that behavior. What you could find useful in Onsen UI for this are the events. You can address the scroll with the mentioned tool in a `postpop` event in case you are using `popPage`, or in any other event listed in [Onsen UI's docs](http://onsen.io/reference/javascript.html).

Hope it helps.